# Combining $('body').on('click') with $(window).resize(function() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering if there is a way to combine identical code of 2 separate functions into 1 function.

In my case:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.some_div', function (e) {
    // Long and fancy code
});

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    // Do the same fancy stuff (identical code)
});
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that the resize function might slow down your client's brwoser / make resizing laggy laggy, see [this](http://gomakethings.com/javascript-resize-performance/) reference on how to prevent that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define a single function which you call under both events:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    console.log('Your code here...');
}

jQuery('body').on('click', '.some_div', doSomething);
jQuery(window).resize(doSomething);
```

Bear in mind that the reference to `this` will be different depending on the event raised, should that be used within your `doSomething` function.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a function to handler both the events and pass this function reference to the event handlers.

```
function myHandler(e) {
    // Long and fancy code
}

jQuery('body').on('click', '.some_div', myHandler);

jQuery(window).resize(myHandler);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's another way to do that.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.some_div', function (e) {
    // Long and fancy code
});

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    $('.some_div').trigger('click')
});
```

Comment: @Tushar yes, you got me.

Answer (score 3):

create a separate function and call it from required locations:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.some_div', function(e){
    myFunction();
});


jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction(){
   // Long and fancy code
}
```

Comment: why are you wrapping the call to myFunction with an anonymous function that does nothing? You could just pass myFunction directly.

Comment: thats very true @Racheet...!