# Using multiple selectors with each having different events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need this:

```
$("#household").children().change(function(){
    alert("changed");
});

$('.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick.delete').click(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

turned into something like this:

```
$("#household").children().change || $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick.delete').click(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

I know the bottom code isn't correct, but I am hoping it explains what I mean. I want the `alert` to be executed if `#household.children()` is changed and `.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick.delete` is clicked, but without writing the code twice.

Comment: Please provide HTML/CSS as well. jsFiddle.net would be usefu;;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the common logic in its own function which is then called by both events:

```
function changed() {
    console.log('changed')
}

$("#household").children().change(changed);
$('.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick.delete').click(changed);
```

Comment: Ok, gotcha.  Wasn't really thinking of this, but it will do just fine.  Thanks, will accept after the time allows.

Comment: Isn't this same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432006/combining-body-onclick-with-window-resizefunction-in-jquery Should be closed as dupe?

Comment: @Tushar good point. I tend to just answer the questions without searching unless it's a really obvious repeat (return AJAX, event binding on dynamic etc)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function elsewhere and pass a reference to it to both event handlers:

```
function somethingChanged() {
  alert('changed');
}

$(...).change(somethingChanged);
$(...).click(somethingChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with jquery only. You could start like this:

```
$("#household,.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick.delete")...
```

but then everything willbe similar (for example both will have click or onchange)